# How to add BOTH static values and records from a table as list items to a combo box in VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-forms

I have a combo box that gets its list items from a query. But in addition to these items, I need one static option that will be there in all cases.

I tried doing this in the naive way:

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
   Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT ESDNodes.Description, ESDNodes.Sort FROM ESDNodes WHERE (((ESDNodes.parentID) =" & parentID & ")) ORDER BY ESDNodes.Sort")
   Set nextSiblingSelect.Recordset = rst
   nextSiblingSelect.AddItem Item:="Make Last", Index:=0
End Sub
```

but end up with this run-time error

> The RowSourceType property must be set to 'Value List' to use this method.

which I half-expected.

Is there any trick around this? I suppose I could add a dummy record to my table set and change the query but that would be rather ugly and I would not prefer it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try a UNION query as the combobox RowSource. Maybe like:

`SELECT Description, Sort FROM ESDNodes 
UNION SELECT "Make Last", 0 FROM ESDNodes ORDER BY Sort;`

Comment: Add TOP 1 to make it more efficient.  Otherwise it must run the full second query then compare all rows just to narrow down to distinct values:  `UNION SELECT TOP 1 "Make Last", 0 FROM ESDNodes ORDER BY Sort`

Comment: So without TOP 1, it compares the "Make Last" record to all records in ESDNodes to check if it is unique?